# Raspberry AM radio transmitter

Tags: radio, pifm

Is there a AM radio trasmitter library for raspberry? Like [PiFMRDS](https://github.com/ChristopheJacquet/PiFmRds) ? AM travels further and it would get better range on low power RPi trasmitter. Or how could I do that myself? Generate high (~1Mhz) frequency and modulate it according to audio input.

Comment: While it might be possible to generate a FM (frequency modulated) signal using a PWM output (I did not test this libary, but it looks interesting), this won't work with AM, since that requires analog electronics for modulation. If it is only about the range, I would rather add some extra power amplifier to the output. Just be aware that you may get into big trouble if you build an FM tranceiver that has a range of more than a few meters.

Comment: Oh, so FM is possible because it is just a PWM signal basically, but AM would need different amplitudes? But it also could be achieved with PWM, no?

Comment: I'm not the expert here, but I would say no, Amplitude modulation would need an analog output. It could probably be done with a fixed frequency PWM signal (as the carrier) and an analog sound output.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is: [rpitx](https://github.com/F5OEO/rpitx)

It does AM as well many other modulations: FM, SSB, etc. All thanks to some cunning PWM.

---

Though, I highly advise you to **go and learn a lot more before using it!** Really, go grab some books on the basics of radio communication and also check the laws and regulations surrounding it. If you fail to do so you may end up disrupting some critical equipment and get yourself in jail.

Your follow-up questions show a lack of understanding of some basic principles. AM does not travel further. AM is just a type of modulation. What travels further are the carrier waves usually employed with AM modulation: they have a lower frequency than those typically used for FM, and can propagate as ground waves, following the Earth's curvature.

Your intention (getting a better range) also shows that you are unaware of the consequences of transmitting on allocated frequencies, specially with a noisy transmitter. You should have read [PiFmRds's Warning and Disclaimer](https://github.com/ChristopheJacquet/PiFmRds#warning-and-disclaimer) more carefully. Let me quote the most important bits:

> In most countries, transmitting radio waves without a state-issued licence
> specific to the transmission modalities (frequency, power, bandwidth, etc.)
> is illegal.
>
> [...]
>
> Even if you are a licensed amateur radio operator, using PiFmRds to
> transmit radio waves on ham frequencies without any filtering between
> the RaspberryPi and an antenna is most probably illegal because the
> square-wave carrier is very rich in harmonics

All this applies to rpitx as well. These are meant as learning and experimentation tools. You should never transmit further than your room, or better, as PiFmRds advises:

> connect a shielded transmission line from the RaspberryPi directly to a radio receiver, so as not to emit radio waves

Comment: +1, but your "go to jail" warning is a bit of an overstatement. Unless the OP builds an actual RF amplifier and a decent antenna, he is unlikely to be discovered at all, let alone go to jail. He will be stuck in a long line of criminal offenders who have bought uncertified RC drones, garage door kits and LED lightbulbs on eBay :)

Answer (score 0):

USB SDR (software defined Radios) exist that will transmit.

However, you have to obtain a legal license to transmit any significant distance.  Thus probably defeating the whole benefit of long distance.

You want to use it as a CB or Ham Radio you need to be legally licensed to do so.  Take a class and pass a test and pay a fee.

At least with an SDR you can choose alternate frequencies that don't collide with AM or etc transmitters.

Still you need to have a license to do what you want.

Comment: You don't need a licence in the PMR (Personal Mobile Radio) bands.  But, as you suggest, it is over a restricted distance.

Answer (score -1):

It is not the distance, it is the ERP (Effective Radiated Power) and the band that can get you into trouble.  By limiting the ERP it has a big effect on distance but on the correct band and atsmopher conditions Amaturer operators have gone thousands of miles. CB across the US with 5 watts power was common in the mid 60's. The best place to increase your distance and not get in trouble is to increase the sensitivity and selectivity of your receiver.

You can purchase commercial communication equipment that will do the job and have a lot more power and range. They will be licenced by the appropriate agency in your country. In the US it is the FCC ()Federal Communications Commission).